# Pulling out a variable constant x with respect to y in double integral dydx

Tags: integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I've found many questions related to taking a "literal constant", such as 3, and pulling it outside of a double integral, but my question pertains to doing this with a variable constant.  In my stats textbook, they do the following:

[image]

I see that $xye^{-(x+y)} = xe^{-x}ye^{-y}$.  Is the idea that they are pulling out the $xe^{-x}$ factor into the outer integral, because it's a constant with respect to the inner integral $dy$?  I'd not seen this done before in my Calc 3 class - we would have just integrated $xe^{-x}ye^{-y}$ with respect to $y$ - so I want to be sure I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea - the factors which only depend on $x$ do not change as you do the $y$ integral, so they can be factored out of that integral.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, what would you get if you just integrated $xe^{-x}ye^{-y}$ w.r. $y$? You’ll end up with a factor of $xe^{-x}$ either way.

Comment: Thank you both.  I look at this question and it seems obvious, but my professor never taught this and so I was a bit rusty in understanding this.  Instead he always had us integrate the full term keeping in mind that any other variables were constants.  I suppose he wanted us to not shy away from integrating terms with numerous variables in it, and get us used to "tougher" integrals.